# Instantiating if null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, null

I often have static classes which uses the `DataContext` somehow, and they all make a new `DataContext`, but often I already have one instantiated elsewhere, so why not use that?

```
public static bool SignIn(string email, string password, DataContext db = null)
{

    bool disposeDb = false;
    if (db == null)
    {
        disposeDb = true;
        db = new DataContext();
    }

    //Sign In stuff, or any other stuff...

    if (disposeDb) db.Dispose();
}
```

But is there a cool trick to do this, or am I just coding it wrong?  Or is it ok?

**Update**

The `DataContext` is not expensive to instantiate.  I guess I just leave it be.

But here is another example:

```
public static User GetUser(DataContext db = null)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Id"] == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        bool disposeDb = false;
        if (db == null)
        {
            disposeDb = true;
            db = new DataContext();
        }

        int id = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Id"].Value);
        string cookieKey = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CookieKey"].Value;

        User user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id && x.CookieKey == cookieKey);

        if (disposeDb) db.Dispose();
        return user;
    }
}
```

This is again nice because if I already have a context, I can provide it, and then I won't have to attach the entity (User) to another context if I want to modify it:

```
User user = MyClass.GetUser(db);
user.Email = "asdsasd";
db.SaveChanges();
```

How can I improve it?  Or is it okay?

**Update 2**

The `DataContext` should only be instantiated once per page request. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10153406/973485) is a neat way to do it, that actually allows me to access it even from static methods.

Comment: I believe that ... since `db` is not passed in be reference, it should be disposed automatically as it falls out of scope when the function exists. Why do you sometimes pass in an instantiated `DataContext`, and why do you want it to auto-dispose. Is it good or bad? Well, it depends. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Not sure if i follow, Well if there is a DataContext paramater is provided, it is because it is instansiated elsewhere, and will be disposed wlsewhere, but if you dont have one, and only need the result of that method, please dispose after use.

Comment: How expensive is it to create a new `DataContext`? If it is expensive, then perhaps you create t once and hold on to it. Does the library provide the connection pooling for you? I do not like your original code (nothing personal), but I cannot tell you exactly how to make it better because I do not see examples of how you are using it. It is weird to me that the `DataContext` may or may not be already created. What control that?

Comment: "I Often have static classes" ??? I would look into why you often have these.  Too many static classes IMHO can sometimes hints at design problems.  Perhaps these are causing you to write code that you are not that keen about?

Comment: @Leonid Not that expensise. so i'll just instasiate those inside. dreza Okay, i don't have that many static classes!

Comment: You want us to kill you? That won't be very productive... who's going to accept our answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see 2 issues with `SignIn` method:

- it is static. It means that you can't unit-test business logic that uses `SignIn` functionality in isolation, you'll have to hit the database in your tests.
- `DataContext` in web applications should usually be instantiated once per web request because in most cases web request represents a unit-of-work, and as such should be covered by a single transaction. If you're using ASP.NET MVC you can move all the logic that deals with `DataConext` instantiation and calling `SaveChanges`/`Dispose` into base controller class, and expose instance of DataContext as a property. That way you business logic will be cleaned from DataContext management, and most likely you won't actually need a separate class with methods like `SignIn` since the functionality can go right into Controller class.

About `GetUser` method - if this a method is in Controller class, and taking previous bullets into consideration, the code would look like that:

```
//MyBaseController exposes DataContext property
public class UserController : MyBaseController
{
    public User GetUser()
    {
        HttpCookie idCookie = Request.Cookies["Id"];
        HttpCookie keyCookie = Request.Cookies["CookieKey"];

        int id;
        if (idCookie == null || keyCookie == null || !int.TryParse(idCookie.Value, out id))
            return null;

        return DataContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id && x.CookieKey == keyCookie.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

At the very least, you should place the second `if` statement in a `finally` block.  As things stand, the code is not generally correct from a purely mechanical perspective.  I would also phrase it as:

```
bool dbDispose = db == null;
db = db ?? new DataContext();
```

From a design point of view: yes, I'd say this violates the single responsibility principle.  You have a method that not only does certain calculations, but also creates a `DataContext` if necessary.  If creation has to be modified at any point, then you'll have many places to change that.  (Unlikely if it's default-constructed like this, but I doubt it's that simple in practice.)

It looks to me like `SignIn` should actually be a member function of `DataContext`.

Comment: Wow, to make SignIn a part of DataContext would be just wrong... just.. or would it? I can't imagen thats how people  make theese kind of functions..

Comment: Making it directly part of a DataContext could be wrong, if that gives `DataContext` too much responsibility.  On the other hand, having a class with a member `DataContext` and a `SignIn` method could definitely make sense.

Answer (score 0):

So, default argument values are nice, but in this case I favor the old-school (multiple methods with the same name) approach

```
public static bool SignIn(string email, string password)
{
    using (var db = new DataContext())
    {
        return SignIn(email, password, db);
    }
}

public static bool SignIn(string email, string password, DataContext db)
{
    Require.IsNotNull(db, "nice error message here"); // Or whatever the syntax is ...
    //Sign In stuff, or any other stuff...
}

... and so on ...
```

I like static methods, Rich Hickey likes static methods. Static methods are one honking good idea! Let's have more of these. The static methods hatas will keep on hating.

Comment: whole `MakeDataContextIfNeeded` method can be rewritten as `db ?? new DataContext()`, there is no need is this method.

Comment: Do you have any sources that the cleanup you expect is likely to happen?

Comment: @Anton Golov, I talked out of my ass. It is generally a bad idea to let an `IDisposable` fall out of scope, so much so that there is a rule specifically for it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289(v=vs.100).aspx Apparently when compiling C++ to .Net, you can rely on the fact that a finalizer will run which will also call Dispose. When using C#, this will not happen for some time. So, an open file will be locked until the GC decides to run. It smells like an undefined behavior and you can code a Schroedingers cat logic around the fact that you do not know whether the file is locked

Answer (score -1):

Instead of init `DataContext` inside static methods you can use **Singleton** pattern or **Factory** pattern depending on what kind of life cycle of the object DataContext. That patterns allows to encapsulate logic of `DataContext` initialization and provide more control over the life cycle of an instance(including implementation caching politics).

As for me correct variant `GetUser` method should look similar on that:

```
public static class UserService{

public static User GetUser(HttpContext context, DataContext db)
{
   if (db==null)
      throw new ApplicationException("Data Context is null");
   if (context==null)
      throw new ApplicationException("Http Context  is null");

    if (context.Request.Cookies["Id"] == null)
    {
       return null;
    }
    else
    {
         int id = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Cookies["Id"].Value);
         string cookieKey = context.Request.Cookies["CookieKey"].Value;

         User user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id && x.CookieKey == cookieKey);

         return user;
    }

}

}
```